# Orchard container without creating list tags

Tags: list, containers, orchardcms

I am using Orchard to create a table-like layout. I have defined two content types: 'Row' and 'Column'. To allow items of the type Column to be added to a Row I added the 'Container' part to the Row and 'Containable' to the Column.

All works fine, the columns show up in the row they were put in, however Orchard renders list tags around my columns which mess up my layout. Is it possible to prevent these list tags from being rendered? I checked out the source of ContainerPartDriver.cs but the 'listShape' seems to be baked in, however I hope someone can prove me wrong.

Comment: Why are you using Content Types for your layout definition? Why not just use your own theme zone layout?

Comment: I am creating something similar to a single page application. The CMS user should be able to add multiple rows to a page where each row may contain a variable amount of columns.
I think I can't achieve this flexibility with zones in the layout.

Comment: Check out the new dynamic layout feature in 1.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I am retrieving the container items and displaying each one in the view itself.

```
@{
    var contentManager = WorkContext.Resolve<IContentManager>(); ;
    var container = (ContentItem)Model.ContentItem;
    var query = contentManager
        .Query(VersionOptions.Published)
        .Join<CommonPartRecord>().Where(x => x.Container.Id == container.Id)
        .Join<ContainablePartRecord>().OrderByDescending(x => x.Position);
}
@foreach (var item in query.List())
{
    @Display(contentManager.BuildDisplay(item, "Detail"));
}
```